# INVALID_ID_FIELD, All targetObjectIds for an email must be of the same type error

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I am getting the below error when the below trigger is triggered. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error -

Error -

Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger EmailService caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: EmailService: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, All targetObjectIds for an email must be of the same type.: []: Trigger.EmailService: line 20, column 1

Code -

```
trigger EmailService on Task__c (after insert) {
    EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name='Multiple Tasks'];
    List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.MassEmailMessage>();

    for(Task__c t : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(t.Project_Approval__c =='Approved' &&t.Status__c == 'Open' ){
            List<Id> lstIds= new List<Id>();
            lstIds.add(t.Task_Executioner__c);
            lstIds.add(t.Task_Executioner_1__c);
            lstIds.add(t.Task_Executioner_2__c);

            Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectIds(lstIds);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Charan Tej');
            mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
            mails.add(mail);
       }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your Task_Executioner fields are referencing multiple different sObjects, and the setTargetObjectIds method will only take Ids from a single sObject.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm) on method setTargetObjectIds of MassEmailMessage:

`The objects must be of the same type (all contacts, all leads, or all users).`

You are likely trying to add mixed IDs to the collection of IDs that you then pass to this method. Please verify that the fields Task_Executioner__c, Task_Executioner_1__c, and Task_Executioner_2__c are IDs, and that they are **all** either contacts, users, or leads.

Comment: All the (t.Task_Executioner__c), (t.Task_Executioner_1__c),           (t.Task_Executioner_2__c); are 3 different fields of same object Task__c and lookup to contact object..

Comment: They all have to be IDs of the same type of object. If one is a Contact, and the other two are Users, this error will be thrown

Comment: All the 3 fields are currently lookup to contact...